# EF Core inherited properties not being reflected in migration script

Tags: inheritance, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I am trying to migrate the below models and the inheritance is not being reflected in the migration script generated.  What am I missing?  I am currently using PM to handle the migration script generation with a simple Add-Migration followed by Update-Database in VS2017 targeting SQL 2016.

```
public class Facility
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public byte? Image { get; set; }

        public List<LocationFacility> LocationFacilities { get; set; }
    }

    public class Helipad : Facility
    {
        public decimal Size { get; set; }
        public decimal MaximumWeight {get; set;}
    }
```

Comment: Can you share migration file generated? Also how are you including type `Helipad` in your model?

Comment: I made a small change this morning and added an extra field.  The migration script is blank.  I haven't done anything more than the above, I didn't think I needed to on reading the MS Docs.

Comment: Adding the Helipad model deriving from Facility to the ApplicationDbContext manually has generated the expected script with TPH inheritance.  I was expecting it to be added during Add-Migration.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Documentation of EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/included-types),

In order to have certain type to be included in the model by convention, either you need DbSet property or Navigation property pointing to the type or refer it in `OnModelCreating`. There is navigation property on `Facility` class. Perhaps some inverse navigation pointing to `Facility` on a type which was included in the model caused `Facility` to be included. But `Helipad` was not added unless you explicitly refer to it. EF Core sets up TPH for types which are **included** in the model & have hierarchy. But it does not try to find types in hierarchy if not included.

To fix the issue, the easiest way is to add DbSet property for the type you want to include in your Derived class of DbContext. If you don't want to expose a DbSet property for the type then you can write following in your `OnModelCreating` method.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Helipad>();
```

Hope this solves the issue.